# Setting values of Input fields with possible null in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular7

I am using following to place values in an Input field.
[Setting values of input fields with Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51096781/setting-values-of-input-fields-with-angular-6)

```
<input matInput placeholder = "ProductName" [(ngModel)]="orderLine.productname">
```

However, sometimes the value maybe null. When placing a question mark ? below, we receive the following error, how does someone place possible blank null value in input, or is not possible?

```
<input matInput placeholder = "ProductName" [(ngModel)]="orderLine?.productname">
```

> The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment at column in [[orderLine?.productname=$event]

Comment: Could we take a look at how you're declaring orderLine in your ts? Are you utilizing a FormGroup() w/ Form Controls?

Comment: hi @dnunez32 we are not using formgroup,  I tried it both ways with model member null ? and not null in declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please split it into two parts as these two are part of ngModel::

```
[ngModel]="orderLine?.price" (ngModelChange)="orderLine.price = $event"
```

Comment: what if there is no field `(price)` is presented in the orderLine object..?

Comment: whats the difference between Mutsahen answer and yours? both seem good by the way, maybe just different flavors of doing things,

Comment: @ganesh045 put if condition to check whether your field exist or not. If your field exist then this will work otherwise it'll skip. Please refer this, you'll find your answer:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37111005/how-to-check-empty-object-in-angular-2-template-using-ngif

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the two-way-binding to one data and one event binding :-

```
[ngModel] = "orderLine?.price"
(ngModelChange) = "orderLine.price = $event"
```

Comment: what if there is no field (price) is presented in the orderLine object..?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `?.` inside ngModel two-way binding, perhaps you can use ternary operator:

```
<input matInput placeholder = "Price" [(ngModel)]="orderLine? orderLine.price: null">
```

Answer (score 0):

we can not use ternary operator `?` in two way binding

```
<input matInput placeholder = "Price" [(ngModel)]="orderLine?.price">
```

if your `orderLine` object something like below then **you don't need to use** this operator...

```
    orderLine= new OrderLine();

    class OrderLine {
         ...
         price: number;
         ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split two-way binding.

```
[ngModel]="orderLine?.price" (ngModelChange)="orderLine.price = $event"
```